# How to suppress file warnings in GDB?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, suppress-warnings

When I *debug* a C-program with **gdb** I often run into warnings like these:

```
66  ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: File or directory not found.
(gdb) step
67  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S
(gdb) s
68  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S
(gdb) s
69  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S
(gdb) s
70  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S
...
```

This keeps going on for a while, until the file is found (I guess). Later the program continues but gdb runs into another unknown file and so on...

What's wrong? How can I get rid of these errors/warning?

Comment: Install the sources for *glibc*, which distribution is that? ... *Assuming Linux*.

Comment: Do you mean *linux-libc-dev* ? I have these installed already.

Comment: On this [site](http://packages.ubuntu.com) you can search the package which contains your file. But, no package seems to actually contain it.

Comment: There's not much point trying to debug standard functions. You should use `next` rather than `step` to step over such functions, instead of stepping into them.

Comment: I don't know how to suppress the error messages, but you can correct the errors by doing (as root) `apt-get install dpkg-dev; mkdir -p /build/buildd; cd /build/buildd; apt-get source eglibc`

Comment: when debugging, it is best practice to 'next' over the standard library functions rather than stepping through them.  Then you will not be presented with all those messages